# Read SAS-macrovariables from Excel ranges

Tags: variables, macros, sas

I was wondering if there is a way to read SAS-macrovariables from Excel book/sheet/cell references?

The macro variable are sorted in column A like this, in a Excel spreadsheet:

```
%let var_1 = 1;
%let var_2 = 2;
%let var_3 = 3;
%let var_4 = 4;
%let var_5 = 5;
%let var_6 = 6;
```

Then in the SAS editor:

```
A datastep or proc sql that will read the SAS-macrovariables from the Excel file;

  Data testSet;
  testVar_1 = &let var_1.;
  testVar_2 = &let var_2.;
  testVar_3 = &let var_3.;
  testVar_4 = &let var_4.;
  testVar_5 = &let var_5.;
  testVar_6 = &let var_6.;
  run;
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Your second data step doesn't quite make sense to me at least.

If you can change your data structure this may work more easily, assuming what you're trying to do is create macro variables.

Structure in excel

```
MVAR_NAME  Value
var_1       1
var_2       2
var_3       3
```

Then in SAS, import the excel file however you normally would, let's assume its called have and create the macro variables:

```
data _null_;
set have;
call symput(mvar_name, value);
run;
```